# Good pratices to append HTML block to send email in Aspnet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In aspnet core I created a Partial View with simple HTML:

```
<div style="background-color:#000;color:#fff;font-size:small">
E-mail enviado pela Quality Administrabem
```

In the _emailSender.SendEmailAsync Method I wanted to insert the content from the Partial View to give a finish to the email. I thought the best way would be to create a Partial View and invoke it there, but the result was the one below.

[image]

And e-mail inbox mail, this is the result:
[image]

I also thought about using StringBuilder, but it would be rework. So what would be the best way to implement this block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using asp.net core `Identity` which is scaffolded by Razor Pages in 2.2.Refer to below demo which passes a model at the same time.

1.Create a `IRazorPartialToStringRenderer` interface and `RazorPartialToStringRenderer` class

```
public interface IRazorPartialToStringRenderer
{
    Task<string> RenderPartialToStringAsync<TModel>(string partialName, TModel model);
}
//class
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
namespace YourNamespace
{
public class RazorPartialToStringRenderer : IRazorPartialToStringRenderer
{
    private IRazorViewEngine _viewEngine;
    private ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public RazorPartialToStringRenderer(
        IRazorViewEngine viewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public async Task<string> RenderPartialToStringAsync<TModel>(string partialName, TModel model)
    {
        var actionContext = GetActionContext();
        var partial = FindView(actionContext, partialName);
        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                partial,
                new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                    metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                },
                new TempDataDictionary(
                    actionContext.HttpContext,
                    _tempDataProvider),
                output,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );
            await partial.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return output.ToString();
        }
    }
    private IView FindView(ActionContext actionContext, string partialName)
    {
        var getPartialResult = _viewEngine.GetView(null, partialName, false);
        if (getPartialResult.Success)
        {
            return getPartialResult.View;
        }
        var findPartialResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, partialName, false);
        if (findPartialResult.Success)
        {
            return findPartialResult.View;
        }
        var searchedLocations = getPartialResult.SearchedLocations.Concat(findPartialResult.SearchedLocations);
        var errorMessage = string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine,
            new[] { $"Unable to find partial '{partialName}'. The following locations were searched:" }.Concat(searchedLocations)); ;
        throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
    }
    private ActionContext GetActionContext()
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            RequestServices = _serviceProvider
        };
        return new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
    }
}
}
```

2.Inject it in startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<IRazorPartialToStringRenderer, RazorPartialToStringRenderer>();
```

3.Use in razor pages bu DI:

```
    //omit other DI
    private readonly IRazorPartialToStringRenderer _renderer;
    public ForgotPasswordModel(IRazorPartialToStringRenderer renderer)
    {
        _renderer = renderer;
    }
```

4.Get partial view to string

```
var body = await _renderer.RenderPartialToStringAsync("_RodapeEmailPadrao",YourModel);
```

Refer to [Rendering A Partial View To A String in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/render-partial-to-string)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `ToString()` is not overriden for the class `PartialViewResult`. A convenient extension method could be:

```cs
public static string ConvertToString(this PartialViewResult partialView, 
                                              ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
      using (var sw = new StringWriter())
      {
        partialView.View = ViewEngines.Engines
          .FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialView.ViewName).View;

        var vc = new ViewContext(
          controllerContext, partialView.View, partialView.ViewData, partialView.TempData, sw);
        partialView.View.Render(vc, sw);

        var partialViewString = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

        return partialViewString;
      }
    }
```

Taken from https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2015/03/partialview-tostring.html

This way you should be able to add it like so `Partial("_RodapeEmailPadrao").ConvertToString(ControllerContext)`.